# How to check if group has a children or not in Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

Is there any function that let us to know if a group has children or not ?,
because if I try like Mygroup.getChildren() in group that doesn't has children i'll get error.
thank's

Comment: Mygroup.getChildren() looks correct and similar code works for me, even if the group has no children.  What error are you getting?  Can you post an example of offending code?

Answer (score 2):

pls check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LvCmT/

```
 if(group.getChildren().length==0)
      {
        alert("group doesn't has children");
      }
      else
      {
        //do ur stuff
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(Mygroup).children().length==0)
  {
    alert("group doesn't has children");
  }
else
  {
    //do your stuff
  }
```